# How to loop through specific workbooks?

Tags: vbscript

I have `wb1,wb2,wb3 .. wb10` open .

I need to execute some commands on `wb1,wb5,wb6`. If I use the `workbooks` collection then it will loop through all workbooks.

```
For Each book In Workbooks
```

Also, `Application` is not available in VBScript.

How can I loop through specific workbooks?

Comment: you need to post more code then you have.  No clue how you are referencing Application or creating objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two ways
1. go by index if you know order like wordkbooks(0),wordkbooks(5) etc
2. more general way go by name

```
`for idx=0 to count
if strcomp(workbook(idx).name,"wb1")=0 or strcomp(workbook(idx).name,"wb2")=0 then
'execute some code
end if
next`
```

Answer (score 3):

The workbook name can be used to access it directly. For example:

```
objExcel.Workbooks("wb1").ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "This is in book 1"
objExcel.Workbooks("wb2").ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "This is in book 2"
```

And, yes, `Application` is not available in VBScript. But you can create it yourself. It's just a reference to the Excel application object.

```
Set Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Answer (score 2):

For processing a subset of the open workbooks in a loop you could create a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) with the names of the workbooks you want to process and restrict processing in your loop like this:

```vbs
Set workbooksToProcess = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
workbooksToProcess.Add "wb1", True
workbooksToProcess.Add "wb5", True
workbooksToProcess.Add "wb1", True

For Each book In xl.Workbooks
  If workbooksToProcess.Exists(book.Name) Then
    ...
  End If
Next
```

or create an array with the names, and process the workbooks like this:

```vbs
workbooksToProcess = Array("wb1", "wb5", "wb6")

For Each name In workbooksToProcess
  Set book = xl.Workbooks(name)
  ...
Next
```

Comment: Avoids the complex boolean expression *and* deals with the loop problem.